# Modificar tamaño de columnas en Excel con Python

Tags: python

Hola estoy editando una archivo de Excel modificando el tamaño de sus columnas actualmente solo e podido modificar el tamaño de una columna con el siguiente código:

```py
import openpyxl

 
informe = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'archivo.xlsx')

sheet = informe.active 

  
sheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 26

informe.save(r'archivo.xlsx')
```

No he podido seleccionar un rango de columnas para cambiar su tamaño, actualmente solo se cambia el tamaño de 1, alguien sabe como puedo modificar el tamaño de un rango que seleccione. Gracias!!

Comment: En el fondo, column_dimensions es un diccionario modificado. Este diccionario modificado no ofrece ninguna forma de acceder a varias, en este caso, columnas, al mismo tiempo. Tendrás que usar un bucle for. Me explico?

Comment: Ejemplo: `for column in ("A", "B", "C"): sheet.column_dimensions[column].width = 26`

Comment: Te sirve el ejemplo que te dí? O necesitas una forma de obtener una lista de todas las columnas?

Comment: @DanteS. Si me sirvió muchas gracias, sabes como podría poner un rango de columnas para no poner un a por una?, ejemplo no poner ("A", "B", "C") si no que poner un rango de columnas

Answer (score 0):

`sheet.column_dimensions` es en realidad en el fondo un un diccionario de Python modificado. Y parece que ninguna de las modificaciones que recibe permiten hacer lo que buscas.

Como te contaba en los comentarios, lo mejor es usar un bucle for para estos casos. Yo mismo creé una función que itera sobre un rango y va modificando la dimensión de las columnas una por una.

Esta función usa una función que ofrece openpyxl para obtener un intervalo de columnas llamada [get_column_interval](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html#openpyxl.utils.cell.get_column_interval)

```
from openpyxl.utils.cell import get_column_interval
import openpyxl

informe = openpyxl.load_workbook(r'prueba.xlsx')

sheet = informe.active 

def set_width_to(sheet, start, stop, width):
    for col in get_column_interval(start, stop):
        sheet.column_dimensions[col].width = width

set_width_to(sheet, "A", "D", width=26)

informe.save(r'archivo.xlsx')
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Bro!