# Formato de celda en Excel con Python

Tags: python

Hola estoy cambiando el formato de algunas columnas de Excel con Python, pero no se como seleccionar varias columnas a la vez para cambiar su formato todo de una, me pueden ayudar, gracias.

Este es el código con el que cambio el formato de solo una columna.

Necesito cambiar varias a la vez para ahorrar líneas de código.

```
for cell in sheet['F']:
    cell.number_format = '0.00'
```

Estoy importando openpyxl

Comment: Puedes usar get_column_interval para obtener un intervalo de columnas e iterar sobre el. Es lo que uso en [mi respuesta a tu primera pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/532949/158880). Estaría bueno que le hechases un vistaso a la documentación. Si necesitas funciones adicionales (como obtener una columna a partir de un indice) hechale un vistaso al submodulo de openpyxl [openpyxl.utils.cell](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.utils.cell.html)

Comment: Además, agradecería mucho que aceptes esa respuesta si es que te sirvió ;)

Comment: @DanteS. Hola, no me sirve el get_column_interval ya que con el recorre columnas seguidas, yo necesito uno que solo se aplique el formato a las columnas que yo le indique. Es decir solo que le aplique el formato a la columna 5,10 y 20, trato de hacerlo así para ahorrarme líneas de código, sabes alguna forma, gracias.

Comment: Crea un bucle for que itere sobre una tupla con las columnas que quieras modificar. Algo como `for column in ('A', 'C', 'Z')`. Luego la variable column (o cualquiera que hayas declarado antes del in) contendrá la columna a modificar.

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Podrías usar `xlsxwriter` y hacerlo con [`worksheet.set_column()`](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html?highlight=set_column#set_column).

De esta forma puedes cambiar el formato y ancho de varias columnas al mismo tiempo.

Ejemplo de uso:

```
# Formato de celda
format1 = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '#,##0.00'})

# Configurar el formato de la columna 1 a la 5 
worksheet.set_column(1, 5, 18, format1)
```

Comment: Si dice que modulo usa. Es la ultima oración en la pregunta. Sin embargo, está bueno ver lo que ofrece un modulo alternativo.

Comment: Como puedo abrir un libro ya existente con xlsxwriter?

Comment: En la documentación de ambas librerías hay información relevante, `openpyxl` puede únicamente dar formato celda por celda o una columna a la vez; `xlsxwriter` como el nombre indica, escribe o crea archivos de Excel, no hay una forma directa de únicamente editar un archivo existente. Podrías utilizar una combinación de ambas librerías.